# CORS Not working for OPTIONS

Tags: cors, asp.net-web-api, owin

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }
```

In our webapiconfig.cs we have the following line at the very top of register:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
config.EnableCors();
```

In our web.config we have the following  under the

```
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
   <!--<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />-->
   <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
   <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

And the following  in httpProtocol.

```
<customHeaders>
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" />
    <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept/>
</customHeaders>
```

Whenever we do an OPTIONS Call from Fiddler, we are getting a 405: Here is what is returned. It looks to me that we have it all set up correctly, and the access-control-allow-methods even says options...so why isn't it working?

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 76
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, AMSConnect-Version, Authorization-Token, AMSConnect-Environment
Date: Wed, 29 Apr 2015 13:26:43 GMT
```

Can anyone see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like your server isn't accepting OPTIONS requests.  Or maybe there's a proxy in front of your server that refuses to pass OPTIONS requests through.  try using a simple diagnostic tool like cURL to send OPTIONS requests to your server.  Try doing it directly on your server first, then, if that works, from a remote machine.